# Let $f \neq 0$. Then $\ker(f)$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $f \neq 0$ be a continuous functional. Is it true that $\ker(f)$ is separable?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: I would guess that $\ker(f)$ is separable if and only if $X$ is separable, since $\ker(f)$ has codimension $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe so. Consider the non-separable space $\ell^\infty$ and consider the functional

$$T:(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\mapsto x_1.$$

The kernel of $T$ is the set of bounded sequences with vanishing first entry. This subspace is isometric to $\ell^\infty$ itself in the obvious way and hence non-separable.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X$ be an uncountable set. Consider the space $l^\infty(X)$ of all bounded functions from $X$ into $\mathbb R$, endowed with the $\sup$ norm. Fix a point $x_0\in X$ and condider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&l^\infty(X)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&\varphi&\mapsto&\varphi(x_0).\end{array}$$The $f$ is continuous, but $\ker f$ is not separable.